# Do 2v2 games affect my Matchmaking Rating for 1v1?

Tags: starcraft-2

What I am thinking. I am playing as Protoss but I want to try different race (Zerg). I am noob playing zerg, so I can't just switch races because opponents would stomp me badly. I thought that I will try 2v2 league, going through placement matches again, ending up in bronze league and not ruining my 1v1 rating.

Does it work like this? Is MMR separated for game modes (1v1, 2v2, etc...)? Or is it associated with me as a player?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Starcraft 2 Matchmaker (and your associated ranking) is specific to both game mode and team partner. You may have several different 2v2 rankings (if you play with different people) and nothing about your 2v2 ranking influences who you face in 1 on 1 matchups.